# Страница не реагирует на изменения в css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Залил сайт на хостинг, при изменении css файла в главном файле не происходят изменения.

Comment: Это может быть по совершенно любой причине, без воспроизводимого примера вашей ошибки никто ничего конкретного вам не скажет.

Comment: Заливаю на хостинг через filezilla, меняю в css допустим фон, в главном index ничего не меняется, хотя если отключить путь к css в head в index, то стили отключаются.

Comment: Очистите кэш страницы или измените ссылку на Ваш файл (можно добавить в конец ссылки `?v=1.01`).

Answer (score 3):

Всё просто, скорее всего ваша страница зависла в кэше, и браузер берёт старую, закэшированную версию.

**Решение для себя:**

Очистить кэш - `ctrl + F5`

**Решение для всех:**

Добавить в ссылку номер версии

```
"mystyle.css?2"
```

Теперь браузер ссылается на новый файл, так как в кэше нету файла с таким названием `"mystyle.css?2"`, соответственно при выпуске новых версий итерируем число.

Answer (score 0):

Очистите кэш страницы, ctrl + shift + R, может быть поможет, а без воспроизводимого примера вашей ошибки, как описали выше, никто вам не сможет помочь, пробуйте еще ctrl + f5

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том что главные файл был php, и к пхп файлу стили подключаются по другому.

Comment: А решения в других предложенных ответах не работают?

Comment: Надо бы как-то поподробнее рассказать...